# Don't get burnout solving this - Who am I?

Tags: riddle

Here's my first attempt at a riddle,hopefully it's not too obvious. Please answer with explanations.

> I have been on Earth too long to remember.
>   It can be said part of me is just ash.
> But don't mistake me as immortal or black-hearted,
> the more I work, the more white I become.
> As a hobby,
>   I have composed lots of artworks you see in art museums,
>   just don't ask me to swim, I don't work well under water.

***Who am I ?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> Charcoal

I have been on Earth too long to remember.

> Coal is created by geological processes over a long period of time

It can be said I am created from ash.

> Charcoal can be generated by slow heating of wood

But don't mistaken me as immortal or black-hearted,
the more I work, the more white I become.

> A charcoal briquette becomes grey and ashy as it burns

As a hobby,
I have composed lots of artworks you see in art museums,

> Charcoal can also be used as an art medium

just don't ask me to swim, I don't work well under water.

> I can't think of any uses for wet charcoal

Comment: I guess its too obvious? I will accept it in 15 minutes.

Comment: funny, I don't remember answering this question, haha

Comment: Wow, that's disconcerting.  I wonder who gets the alert if I type @Matt

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Not me. In case some people are suspecting, I can assure you me and him are two different people.

Comment: No, there's Two Matts =D  The one that commented is not the one that posted.

Comment: This is going to mean nothing in the context of the comment, but I got the notification.

Answer (score 1):

## Partial Answer

You are

> a diamond

It can be said I am created from ash.

> Diamonds are said to be created from ash.

But don't mistaken me as immortal or black-hearted,

> Some diamonds are Black Diamonds

the more I work, the more white I become.

> If you shine a light through it, it displays all the colors that makeup white light.

As a hobby,
I have composed lots of artworks you see in art museums,

> Diamonds, and artwork made from diamonds, is on exhibit, everywhere.

just don't ask me to swim, I don't work well under water.

> Diamonds don't float

Comment: This can be an potential alternative, but it won't explain how it becomes more "white" after work.

Comment: I'll wedge it into the slot, then!  Hahaha